# Placing $200$ points in an interval of $(0,200)$, find the probability that in the interval $(0,3)$ there will be one and only one point

Tags: probability

I am not sure how to think about the following question ([source](http://www.engr.usask.ca/classes/EE/845/Quizzes_and_solutions/Solutions_Quizzes_and_Final_2007_2008.pdf), pg. 12):

[image]

What does it mean by "place" and "point"?

If by "place", it means to associate a point with an element in the interval $(0,200)$, then the problem is that there are uncountably many points. The size of the sample space $S$ would be an arbitarily large number. The probability of finding even a single point in an infinitestimal interval would be zero.

Can someone provide some assistance on the interpretation of this question?

Comment: I assume they mean to speak of a uniform distribution.  Thus, the probability that a single choice is in $[0,3]$ is $\frac 3{200}$.

Comment: But for uniform distribution, the sample space is discrete, no? i.e. $S = \{0, 1, \ldots, 200\}  \neq (0,200)$. And why is the probability $3/200$? Shouldn't it be $1/200$

Comment: What is meant is a uniform distribution over the (continuous) interval $(0,200),$ so the sample space is continuous. The probability mentioned by lulu is $3/200$ because the interval $(0,3)$ is $3/200$ the size of the interval $(0,200).$

Comment: If you want, think of a continuous uniform distribution as a limit of discrete ones.

Comment: You could treat this as a Binomial distribution problem.  Either a point is in the subinterval $(0, 3)$ or it is not.  Then $p = 3/200$ and $1 - p = 197/200$.  You want the probability that $P(X = 1)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chance of the first point being placed in the interval $(0, 3)$ is $\frac3{200}$. The chance of every other point not being in the interval is $\left(\frac{197}{200}\right)^{199}$. Multiply these two values to get the correct probability that only the first point is on $(0, 3)$: $\frac{3\cdot197^{199}}{200^{200}}$.

Because there are 200 possible points that could uniquely be in the interval, we must multiply that number by 200, yielding $3\cdot\left(\frac{197}{200}\right)^{199}\approx0.14822=14.822\%$.